# React загружает CSS после того как загрузился HTML, как с этим быть? Выглядит ужасно ;c

Tags: html, css, reactjs

**React** загружает **CSS** после того как загрузился **HTML**, видно чистый **HTML** на протяжении **500млс** и это выглядит не очень красиво. Собственно вопрос, как с этим бороться?

Comment: Проблему решил добавив кусок CSS для начальной разметки прямо в HTML, но это не решение так-как пришлось рендерить SCSS. Все еще жду помощи.

Comment: В реакте нет html, кроме страницы с <div id="root">, так что проблема не в скорости загрузки, а в рендере. Оптимизируйте рендер. По поводу CSS, как он добавляется на страницу? Приведите код

Comment: Добавить загрузку css в шапку сайта/приложения, а не в футер